# Palindrome in a cesarian code

Tags: cipher, steganography, palindrome

Here's some album art from my favorite album "Trinity" by "Sons of Perdition":
[image: Album cover]
I've learned from reliable sources that the coordinates on this map are actually a **cesarean cipher with a shift of**

> 12

, which resolves to a famous Latin palindrome

> in girum imus nocte et consumimur igni

However I can't wrap my head around on how to resolve numbers into letters, as their count do not match the number of letters in the palindrome.

That's the best quality of this image I have, and struggle to read the numbers myself, but I think the numbers are the following:

```
  19 1 12 23 10 5 25 5 10 23 12 1 19 26 1 18 
1                                            5
12                                           8
23                                           10
10                                           1
5                                            18
25                                           1
   5 10 23 12 1 19 26 1 18 5 8 10 1 18 1 14
```

---

BeastlyGerbil - Some edited pictures [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miQWw.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc0vy.jpg)

Comment: can you provide a version that is large enough to read? or can you type the numbers maybe?

Comment: Do you have a picture with a higher resolution or could you provide the coordinates around the map as text? I find them hard to read.

Comment: Sorry, It's the best I have. I'm struggling to read it too, but I will try to write them down

Comment: it's weird. the sentence you provided has 32 letters. 38 with spaces. there are 44 numbers around the map. maybe only the ones on the top or bottom should be used? or some letters are represented by two numbers?

Comment: When I squint I can read the numbers clockwise starting from the top left corner with what looks like a 29. That 29 occurs again under the "Special Guests" block and just repeats the numbers after that. That doesn't explain that the sentence is a palindrome, though, because reading the numbers anticlockwise from the bottom 29 doesn't yield the same number sequence.

Comment: actually if you go towards left from the bottom 29 and right from the top 29, you get the same sequence. so maybe it's just our reading direction which is wrong

Comment: @MOehm My initial thought that this could be reduced to a nuber sequence in some way, so that it could be later be resolved to ascii. But from what I know, modern crypticism is not the authors style

Comment: II can edit the picture to make it bigger and have better resolution, I'll post it as answer and you can copy it into your question

Comment: There is no ASCII code here. The numbers probably just correspond to letters 1=a, 2=b, 3=c and so on until 26=z. Therefore it is strange that there is a 29; maybe it's 19. If we are looking for a palindrome, there is a symmetry around the 14 in the bottom right corner. The letters in the vicinity are "zareh jaran araj heraz", which you can shift 4 times to get "devil never even lived". (That's not Latin, of course. And your palindrome has an odd number of letters and therefore two equal letters, the e, in the middle.)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Why not just edit the question or post the link as a comment?

Comment: @LukasRotter, good point

Comment: @MOehm that's what I thought, but there's only 24 letters in Latin alphabet, and we can clearly see 29,26,35 here, so it's not as straightforward

Comment: I think that the 35 you have transcribed isn't very clear; it might well be a 15. The 26 can be a 26; we don't know whether they used a modern Latin alphabet where I and j and u and v are distinct characters. Only the 29 really loks like a 29 to me. There are 16 numbers in the top and bottom rows. maybe they are the "meat" of the 32-letter message and the numbers to the left and right are needed for decoding?

Comment: @MOehm I have a strong feeling that this is 24-letter alphabet, because ROT12 is used. ROT12 is special because it ciphers both ways, like a cycle, this fits with the palindrome theme, and it's riddle (the circling moth). I like the "Meat" theory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I *think* this might be it... It doesn't match the latin phrase you mentioned, but it does fit the same themes, and those of the album itself (yes, I was listening to it while I solved it). It involves both palindromes and an [ouroborus](https://sonsofperdition.bandcamp.com/track/the-serpent).

Firstly, you have to read the digits as follows:

```
  19 1 12 23 10 5 25 5 10 23 12 1 19 26 1 18 
1                                            5
12                                           8
23                                           10
10                                           1
5                                            18
25                                           1
   5 10 23 12 1 19 26 1 18 5 8 10 1 18 1 14
```

Which mapped to letters gives (1=A, 26=Z):

```
  S A L W J E Y E J W L A S Z A R
A                                 E
L                                 H
W                                 J
J                                 A
E                                 R
Y                                 A
  E J W L A S Z A R E H J A R A N
```

Apply a ROT4 caesar shift:

```
  W E P A N I C I N A P E W D E V
E                                 I
P                                 L
A                                 N
N                                 E
I                                 V
C                                 E
  I N A P E W D E V I L N E V E R
```

Giving a palindrome that overlaps itself starting in multiple places. Eg. running from the top left:

**We panic in a pew. Devil never even lived. *(repeat)***

Comment: The author himself has told me that he used ROT12. It seems that he had forgotten :D

Comment: @Benedictus - that's pretty funny. ...maybe just trying to throw you off track. :)

Comment: exactly my thoughts :D